# Custom validation rules entered by a user for an object

Tags: json, validation, groovy, customization, custom-validators

In my current project we have the following list of requirements for one of our microservices:

1. Any object can have the list of custom validation rules and validation rules might differ between objects (it might even be that an object has the list of unique validation rules)
2. Those custom validation rules can be configured from UI by a user who created initial version of the object
3. Any time when some specific events happen with the object(changes and updates) we need to verify that the changes do not violate any of custom validation rules entered in the beginning
4. We also should have the list of standard checks like date range checks, number of some items and elements in the object

***For now we are going to save all of this validation rules for objects either***

- as **JSON** object that will contain details of validation rule
- or serialized **Groovy** object (*Validator)

In both cases it will be saved in database and used any time when it is needed to go throught the list of validations rules and execute them.

I am not sure that both options are the best and may be there are some other ways to implement it. Do you know **any patterns or approaches** that can help to implement custom validation rules?

Thank you

Comment: better to use some declarative language (json in your options) then scripting because later you can generate documentation or do some visualization of this declaration. and reading your requirements (services, object definition/validation)  - what do you think about http://swagger.io/

Comment: IMHO in the very end you will have a bunch of Java code pieces regardless of you are using some "buit-in" 3rd party libraries, like Hibernate or your custom-made Json descriptions. And if you need some hardcore logic (like calling remote server or counting stars in the sky) it will be really tricky to implement in Json pojos. That's why I'm voting for Groovy implementation: 1) easy and clear coding 2) easy integration and good performance with cache of compiled scripts 3) possibility of providing own library of validators

Answer (score 0):

For custom validations implementation I'd suggest you to use Java validation API. It's very powerful in conjunction with validation groups.
You initialize beans / appropriate POJO instances based on the user inputs, and then simply call validations like: Validator.validate(T object, java.lang.Class... groups)

Comment: I like Java Bean Validation API, but it is not a case where we can use it. The idea is that a user can enter his custom validation rule for an item in the system.